# MSSQL - Select DATETIME from stuff(cast(convert()) for each seperated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I current have this WORKING query:

```
SELECT G.ID,
       G.EmployeeName,
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT Cast(',' AS VARCHAR(max))
                              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Count(U.UserID))
              FROM   ActivityLog U
              WHERE  U.UserID = G.ID
                     AND StartDateTime >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
                     AND EndDateTime <= '2014-07-01 23:59:59.000'
              GROUP  BY Year(StartDateTime),
                        Datepart(wk, StartDateTime)
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS ActivityCount
FROM   OperatorDetail G,
       ActivityLog AL
GROUP  BY G.ID,
          G.EmployeeName
ORDER  BY ActivityCount DESC
```

Which returns this:

```
ID   EmployeeName    ActivityCount 
1    John Spoon      30, 50, 33, 90
2    Dave Jones      51, 88
3    Andy Carr       10, 22, 77, 44, 50
```

How can I change my query for it to show the average date collected for each value that's separated by a comma using StartDateTime and EndDateTime which is in `ActivityLog`?

My desired outcome would be something like:

```
ID   EmployeeName    ActivityCount          Dates
1    John Spoon      30, 50, 33, 90         2014-10-01 00:00:00, 2014-10-01 22:00:00, 2014-10-04 07:00:00, 2014-10-10 09:00:00
2    Dave Jones      51, 88                 2014-10-03 08:00:00, 2014-10-06 17:00:00
ect...
```

I have tried this below but I get the error `Type U.StartDateTime is not a defined system type.`

```
    SELECT G.ID,
       G.EmployeeName,
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT Cast(',' AS VARCHAR(max))
                              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Count(U.UserID))
              FROM   ActivityLog U
              WHERE  U.UserID = G.ID
                     AND StartDateTime >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
                     AND EndDateTime <= '2014-07-01 23:59:59.000'
              GROUP  BY Year(StartDateTime),
                        Datepart(wk, StartDateTime)
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS ActivityCount,
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT Cast(',' AS VARCHAR(max))
                              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CONVERT(U.STARTDATETIME, Getdate()))
              FROM   ActivityLog U
              WHERE  U.UserID = G.ID
                     AND StartDateTime >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
                     AND EndDateTime <= '2014-07-01 23:59:59.000'
              GROUP  BY Year(StartDateTime),
                        Datepart(wk, StartDateTime)
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS Dates
FROM   OperatorDetail G,
       ActivityLog AL
GROUP  BY G.ID,
          G.EmployeeName
ORDER  BY ActivityCount DESC
```

`StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` values are in this format: '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000', (`datetime, null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cross join (Cartesian product) between the 2 tables, I can only assume that is deliberate. I firmly believe that you should make this obvious by using the ANSI standard syntax `CROSS JOIN`. If it is NOT deliberate then you need to specify how the 2 tables join.

You are also use a strange date combination for the date range. The 1st of June through to and including the 23rd hour, 59th minute and 59th second of the 1st of July. That is very nearly 1 month and 1 day.

Seems to me you should be using >= '20140601' and < '20140701' (all of July 2014, one month exactly)

For the concatenation it is just a small tweak to the syntax, where you calculate the min()? max()? date, convert that average to a format using style number 120, very much like what you are already doing to the count.

```
SELECT
      G.ID
    , G.EmployeeName
    , STUFF((
            SELECT
                  CAST(',' AS varchar(max)) + CONVERT(varchar(30), COUNT(U.UserID))
            FROM ActivityLog U
            WHERE U.UserID = G.ID
                  AND StartDateTime >= '20140601'
                  AND EndDateTime < '20140701'
            GROUP BY
                  YEAR(StartDateTime)
                , DATEPART(wk, StartDateTime)
            FOR xml PATH ('')
      )
      , 1, 1, '') AS ActivityCount
    , STUFF((
            SELECT                                                -- change can't use avergae
                  CAST(',' AS varchar(max)) + CONVERT(varchar(30), MAX(U.StartDateTime), 120)
            FROM ActivityLog U
            WHERE U.UserID = G.ID
                  AND StartDateTime >= '20140601'
                  AND EndDateTime < '20140701'
            GROUP BY
                  YEAR(StartDateTime)
                , DATEPART(wk, StartDateTime)
            FOR xml PATH ('')
      )
      , 1, 1, '') AS Dates

FROM OperatorDetail G
CROSS JOIN ActivityLog AL
GROUP BY
      G.ID
    , G.EmployeeName
ORDER BY
      ActivityCount DESC
```

Oh, and you don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` if you are doing a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, with this I get this error: `Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator.`

Comment: Ah, yes of course, sorry. So what do you want here? MIN()? MAX()?

Comment: Isn't AVG possible? I was hoping to return the average date for the `ActivityCount` values

Comment: no it isn't, it would require much more information about your data to come up with some appropriate calculation (maybe!) you can average durations, but not dates.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT G.ID,
       G.EmployeeName,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Count(U.UserID))
              FROM   ActivityLog U
              WHERE  U.UserID = G.ID
                     AND StartDateTime >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
                     AND EndDateTime <= '2014-07-01 23:59:59.000'
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS ActivityCount,
       Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), StartDateTime)
              FROM   ActivityLog U
              WHERE  U.UserID = G.ID
                     AND StartDateTime >= '2014-06-01 00:00:00.000'
                     AND EndDateTime <= '2014-07-01 23:59:59.000'
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS Dates
FROM   OperatorDetail G,
       ActivityLog AL
GROUP  BY G.ID,
          G.EmployeeName
ORDER  BY ActivityCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this returns just the same date each time just once for each row. e.g. `1, John Spoon, 30, 50, 33, 90, Oct 14 2014 11:45AM` `2, Dave Jones, 51, 88, Oct 14 2014 11:45AM`

Comment: @user1626410 - checknow

Comment: I get this error now: `Column 'ActivityLog.StartDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
`

Comment: @user1626410 - show the activity log table data. why you need group by there. Remove group by and check.

Comment: @user1626410 If you put the data in sqlfiddle it vl b easy to fix

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I have created a SQLFiddle but because the activitylog is so huge i've put some custom values in, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0d4c/2

Comment: Again this just shows one date for the whole row, I want it to show  the dates for each activitycount value found in one row, so if it shows two values e.g. (1, 2) show the two average dates for them two values in `Dates`

Comment: That's almost right, however I do need the COUNT around useriD because this will soon be moved in to PHP and displayed in a chart,  however, when I re-add the count it no longer shows comma separated values in `ActivityCount`

Comment: @user1626410 added the count of userid and edited the answer . check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0d4c/3

Comment: The `activitycount` needs to be somehow comma separated per each `dates`

Answer (score 0):

To combine them, you will want to use `group_concat()` on the query.

The way it works is you `LEFT JOIN` your `ActivityLog` table, and then you will ask it to group by the join condition (probably activity_id or something similar).

From there, your select bit will have this in it:

`group_concat(distinct concat(ActivityLog.start_date) order by ActivityLog.start_date)`

This should work, but may need some tweaking.

Edit.

This will work without the need for a nested query; which is good, because nested queries are often slow, and they get cached badly.

Edit 2:

**Just realised, this is for MsSQL. My Answer is MySQL, and may not work in MsSQL. I'll leave answer here for legacy, and incase anybody else needs this and is able to use MySQL instead. However, it may not work in MsSQL.**

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately as you suggested this doesn't work in MsSQL, as `GROUP_CONCAT()` isn't a valid function for MsSQL

Comment: It may be possible to do this with just `concat()` though I don't use MsSQL and so cannot really give any code examples

Comment: I tried adding `concat(AL.StartDateTime, ','),` under `SELECT G.ID,  G.EmployeeName` and adding `LEFT JOIN
 ActivityLog AL
 ON
 AL.UserID = G.ID` after `FROM OperatorDetail G` but the query looks like it's just looping for ever.

Comment: Can you try putting it on SQLfiddle.com so we can see it running?

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I have created a SQLFiddle but because the activitylog is so huge i've put some custom values in, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0d4c/2